# url rewrite how to send everything else to index.php condition

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

there,

This sould be a simple task for anyone who knows, but I am new to Apache rewrites, so please bear with me.
I wrote 2 rewrite conditions and they work. I need to write a third - so that everything else would go to index.php file. The problem is - if I add the third rule, it is always applied despite first 2.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule   ^new/?$   new.php  [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^thanks(.*)$ thankyou.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in the following paragraph about the [L flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) used with the RewriteRule directive:

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in
>    sections, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that **once
>   the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or 
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start.** Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.

I think what happens is that after the rewrite is executed, somehow control is given back to the URL parsing engine and the rules are run again.

You can prevent this behaviour by adding a few rewrite conditions to the last rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule new/?$ new.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule thanks(.*)$ thankyou.php [NC,L]

# Only rewrite to index.php if the current request is not for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. And congrats for your first 1K.